# Use python to get friendslists on facebook

Tags: python, facebook

How can i use python to login to facebook,
grab a friendlist from my friends and use the data to see
if my friends are facebook buddies ?

Thanks for your help :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, you won't be able to get access to your friends' friends list unless they themselves authorize your application.

This being said, you can try the pyfacebook library with the `friends.get()` method or the new graph API.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends will get a list of your friends then
https://graph.facebook.com/{{ID}}/friends will get the friends of your friend with id {{ID}}
```

HTH